# Django Factory Boy - Reverse dependencies (reverse ForeignKey) common recipy

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am new to FactoryBoy. I am trying the example for the exact example in the docs: [reverse dependencies](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#reverse-dependencies-reverse-foreignkey) .

1) Is it correct that the "UserLogFactory" mentioned is "so obvious" one should make it oneself as in:

```
class UserLogFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserLog
```

2) I am getting an `AttributeError`:

> type object 'UserLog' has no attribute 'ACTION_CREATE'

I searched the internet, I found 1 reference ([github error report](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/214)) who seemed to have solved it himself the same day. He did not mention the solution, but from his comments, I gather it is something obvious...

Thanks in advance for the help!
Kind regards.

Answer (score 5):

As per factory-boy docs regarding [RelatedFactory](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.RelatedFactory) and [SubFactory](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.SubFactory),
named parameters you define in `RelatedFactory` creation will be passed to `UserLogFactory`, so that `action` is expected to be field in UserLogFactory.

```
log = factory.RelatedFactory(UserLogFactory, 'user', action=models.UserLog.ACTION_CREATE)
```

AttributeError occurs because UserLog lack the constant definition for ACTION_CREATE, which I assume is one of possible choices for `UserLog.action` field.

This is possible way to define `UserLog` model:

```
class UserLog(models.Model):
    ACTION_CREATE = 'CREATE'
    ACTION_UPDATE = 'UPDATE'

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        (ACTION_CREATE, 'create'),
        (ACTION_UPDATE, 'update'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    action = models.CharField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
```

For more information on `choices` take a look at [Django choices docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for the answer; clear. In the meantime I found https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/58 where the example code basically shows the same: one should read "ACTION_CREATE" as something to make oneself. Am I the only one to find this a little unclear? What I see of factory_boy I love, but I am having a little trouble with the docs...

Comment: That issue is not directly related to your problem. It is about names collision and it's fixed. You could reopen issue you mentioned in the question in order to fix this particular docs inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example, the `models.UserLog.ACTION_CREATE` is actually an attribute (value of it to be precise) of the `UserLog` model. I.e. it is irrelevant to the task at hand. Therefore you can just drop it.

It is the same as if the UserLog model had a `created_at` field, or any other field. They just show you that you are able to specify values of the related factory itself.